# Why when searching for an item in Tree View there is never a match?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the textBox2 i type a word/string for example Hello and i checked Hello does exist but it never color it in Yellow.  I used a breakpoint and it never pass this line and color it in Yellow: `if (tn.Text == this.textBox2.Text)`

```
private void FindByText()
{
    TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView1.Nodes;
    foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
    {
        FindRecursive(n);
    }
}

private void FindRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
    {
        // if the text properties match, color the item
        if (tn.Text == this.textBox2.Text)
            tn.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

        FindRecursive(tn);
    }
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    FindByText();
}
```

EDIT

This is an example image of what i want to do: Free search text: I type in textBox2 for example na or hello and it will highlight anywhere the places hello for example. in nodes names in nodes childs inside nodes anyhwere just like it is in the image.

Ofcourse if i type only a or b or c don't highlight it but do highlight any string i type in the textBox2 that is longer then 2 letters

The image is only for example to show what i need to it to do:

[image: Highlight]

Comment: Did you take into account the CASE or extra whitespace that might be in there ? ow about if (tn.Text.Contains(this.textBox2.Text.Trim())

Comment: I would use else statement to color it red and see if that's going to color it at all..

Comment: Also you are running a Depth-First search in the primary UI thread. Which will freeze the UI during the search operation

Comment: I would use the `Tag` property to find what you are looking for.

Comment: First i tried to use fahadash idea and when i type only part of node name if a node name is hello world so if i type only hello it will color in yellow all the items inside all the nodes. I mean when i click on any node '+' and it expand it so all the sub nodes/items are in yellow. And thats for all the nodes.

Comment: `it never pass this line` Just to check: Does the execution enter `FindByText`/`FindRecursive`?

Comment: What i want to do is to search for free text. I mean that when i type a keyword in textBox2 for example Hello so anywhere in the treeview if inside a node or in a part of a node name highlight only the word hello, color in yellow only the word hello ! dont color all the nodes or name or items only highlight the word hello.

Comment: default locale yes it's getting to the if in the foreach before the line that color.

Comment: @YoramBinur Probably you should find the suspected match (node with "Hello" text) and then output and compare `tn.Text` and `textBox2.Text`.

Comment: Updated/edisted my question with example image of what i mean by free search text. Highlight the word i search for anywhere in the treeView1. Ofcourse if i type only a or b or c don't highlight it but do highlight any string i type in the textBox2 that is longer then 2 letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never check the top level, only the their children
(note: the way you do the comparison may need fixing as others have said, but that is a different issue.)

```
private void FindByText()
{
    TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView1.Nodes;
    foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
    {
        if (n.Text == this.textBox2.Text)
            n.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        FindRecursive(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use following code:

```
private void FindRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
{
    // Use this condition if you want a case sensitive search, else use treeNode.Text.ToLower() == this.textBox2.Text.ToLower()
    if (treeNode.Text == this.textBox2.Text)
          treeNode.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    else 
          treeNode.BackColor = Color.White; // Here use your default background color

    foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
    {
        FindRecursive(tn);
    }
}
```